# Jquery load data from URL or go to URL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url

I have 2 php pages named "personal_info" and "portfolio". I load them via php functions in codeigniter `http://www.mysite.com/controller/personal_info` and `http://www.mysite.com/controller/portfolio`.

I have a page with menu tabs linked to personal_info and portfolio and I want to load the pages via ajax when a tab is clicked. If js is turned off in the browser the tabs should just go to the url.

I am using the jquery `.load()` function to load the pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#personal_info').click(function() {
        $('#result').load('personal_info #load'); //load fragments from #load div
    }); 

    $('#portfolio').click(function() {
        $('#result').load('portfolio #load');
    });         
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="tab"><a href="http://www.site.com/portfolio/edit/general_info" id="general_info">General Info</a></div>

<div id="tab"><a href="http://www.site.com/portfolio/edit/portfolio" id="portfolio">Portfolio</a></div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Issue: When I click on a tab it treats it as a link and goes to the URL instead of loading the page via jquery. How can I disable the link if javascript is on? Also, I noticed that javascript is not loaded from fragments in the pages, and if I put the javascript in the page I load data it doesn't pick it up.

What is a good solution for this?

EDIT:

For loading js, I just wrapped the entire page in the `result` div and am loading the other pages with the js and header, footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first issue: put `return false;` at the end of each 'click' function:

```
$('#personal_info').click(function() {
    $('#result').load('personal_info');
    return false;
});
```

Edit: For the second issue, maybe pull out any jquery/javascript and run it from a central application.js file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the default action of the `<a/>` element.  You can accomplish this by using [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$('#personal_info').click(function(e) {
    $('#result').load('personal_info');
    e.preventDefault();
}); 

$('#portfolio').click(function(e) {
    $('#result').load('portfolio');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To stop the default action from occurring (following the link) you need to use `return false` at the end of your jQuery click() functions.

With regard to your second issue ("javascript is not loaded from the [dynamically loaded] pages"), ensure that you are using jQuery's .live functionality to attach handlers.

Comment: .live handlers still wont fire if the javascript is defined on the dynamically loaded pages though, right? He'd need to use .live() within a js declaration that was loaded before the ajax calls, whether it's through an application.js loaded in the header, or within a script tag inside of document.ready from the initially loaded page.

Comment: live() will "Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future." (http://api.jquery.com/live/) If the live() calls occur in the main page, the handlers will be attached to the matched elements in the dynamically-loaded pages.

Comment: Right... but I think he is saying he is defining javascript within the page that is dynamically loaded... So if he is returning ajax_loaded_page.html, somewhere in there he has a <script> tag defining some js that isnt getting run when the ajax page loads... 

In which case he would need to define that javascript outside of the dynamically loaded page.

Comment: If the OP is loading an entire HTML document, and has defined script tags in the head of the document, then I agree. However, if he is loading a partial document, or is including script tags within the body of the loaded document, they should execute at load time.